# Why is using rdeepseq not sufficient to finish reading from a handle before closing it?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I've been slowly making my way through [Real World Haskell](https://book.realworldhaskell.org/). In [Chapter 24](https://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html#id677123), the authors detail a program for reading a file in chunks and then processing it MapReduce-style. However, it fails with `hGetBufSome: illegal operation (handle is closed)`. The program, pared down to an MRE and updated to modern Haskell, is as follows:

```hs
import Control.Exception (finally)
import Control.Parallel.Strategies (NFData, rdeepseq)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB
import GHC.Conc (pseq)
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  res <- chunkedReadWith id (head args)
  print res

chunkedReadWith ::
  (NFData a) =>
  (LB.ByteString -> a) ->
  FilePath ->
  IO a
chunkedReadWith process path = do
  (chunk, handle) <- chunkedRead path
  let r = process chunk
  -- the RHS of finally is for some reason being run before the handle is
  -- finished being used. removing it allows the program to run, with the obvious
  -- disadvantage of leaving closing the handle to the garbage collector
  (rdeepseq r `seq` return r) `finally` hClose handle

chunkedRead ::
  FilePath ->
  IO (LB.ByteString, Handle)
chunkedRead path = do
  h <- openFile path ReadMode
  chunk <- LB.take 64 <$> LB.hGetContents h
  rdeepseq chunk `pseq` return (chunk, h)
```

I suspect this is a problem with inadequately forcing strict evaluation, but my current understanding of `seq`/`pseq` and `Strategies` tells me that the program as written should work, because reduction to normal form should mean that the `handle` has already been read from by the time `hClose` is evaluated. What have I missed?

On a small side note, it's unclear why the authors chose to use `seq` in one place and `pseq` in the other, but since my example has removed any parallel operation, it shouldn't (and indeed doesn't) make a difference.

Comment: The `NFData` instance for lazy bytestrings has `rnf (Chunk _ b) = rnf b`, which seems suspicious. (The first field is a strict bytestring containing the first chunk of data, and it is not forced by this code.) I wonder if it could be that enough IO has been forced for the lazy bytestring to know that it is a `Chunk _ Empty` -- i.e. the size of the file has been read and determined to be bigger than 64 -- but not enough IO has been done to actually read the content of that first chunk! In any case, this seems like a bug worth reporting to the bytestring folks, if only to see what they say.

Comment: @DanielWagner Interesting. Indeed, using strict bytestrings avoids the error but quickly OOMs (in the full program) on large files. I'll file a bug.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/haskell/bytestring/issues/567) the bug for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [this comment](https://github.com/haskell/bytestring/issues/567#issuecomment-1351661389) on the bug I filed,

> The `NFData` instance for `LazyByteString` is correct, albeit perhaps
> written obtusely. Note that the `Chunk` constructor's `S.ByteString` field
> is a strict field, and the `NFData` instance for `StrictByteString`
> evaluates only to WHNF.
>
> The problem is elsewhere: It's that `rdeepseq chunk` is an `Eval LazyByteString` object that can reach WHNF (as witnessed by `seq` or
> `pseq`) before `chunk` has actually been `deepseq`'ed. Try `withStrategy rdeepseq chunk` instead.

In other words, it seems merely applying `rdeepseq` is not enough. Instead, we must use [`withStrategy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.2.0/docs/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#v:withStrategy) (or `using`, alternately) to actually apply the strategy. It seems likely that `rnf` from the 1.x API had slightly different behavior. There is an [`rnf` in `Control.DeepSeq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.4.8.0/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html#v:rnf) that seems to behave similarly.

Concretely, replacing the offending line with the following fixes the problem:

```hs
  (withStrategy rdeepseq r `seq` return r) `finally` mapM_ hClose handles
```

Alternately using `deepseq`, we could more concisely say

```hs
(rnf r `seq` return r) `finally` mapM_ hClose handles
```

or even

```hs
(r `deepseq` return r) `finally` mapM_ hClose handles
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even notice the `r` in `rdeepseq`! A simpler solution would be simply to use `deepseq` or `rnf` (in both places), using ```r `deepseq` return r``` and ```chunk `deepseq` return (chunk, h)```, or ```rnf r `seq` return r``` and ```rnf chunk `pseq` return (chunk, h)```.